# Binding property model value to array with the value from checkbox and inputbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am implementing the `v-for` as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    PaymentType:[
    {Id: 1, Text:"Cash"},
      {Id: 2, Text:"Check"},
      {Id: 3, Text:"Paypal"}
   ],
   SelectedType:[]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p> SelectedType {{ SelectedType }}</p>
  <div v-for="(pay, index) in PaymentType">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="SelectedType" :value="{PayTypeId: pay.Id}" />
    {{pay.Text}}
    
    
    <input type="input" v-model="SelectedType" />
    <!-- What goes here on :value attributes? -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="app">
      <p> SelectedType {{ SelectedType }}</p>
      <div v-for="(pay, index) in PaymentType">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="SelectedType" :value="{PayTypeId: pay.Id}"/> />     
          {{pay.Text}}
          <input type="input" v-model="SelectedType" :value=""/> 
           <!-- What goes here on :value attributes? -->
      </div>
</div>
```

Initially `SelectedType` is empty array object.

Is there any way in Vue to push the Id's to the `PayTypeId` and the value from the input to `Remarks`, on same array objects?

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    PaymentType:[
      {Id: 1, Text:"Cash"},
      {Id: 2, Text:"Check"},
      {Id: 3, Text:"Paypal"}
   ],
   SelectedType:[]
  }
})
```

`SelectedType` is an array of object, it signature looks like `SelectedType:[{PayTypeId:0, Remarks:''}]`.

Is it possible to map the value from checkbox and input box to a Array of Object?

Comment: You want the value in the input text to be added to the array, is that it?

Comment: yes. from input and checkbox into same array object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a bit complicated. The cleanest solution I see is to:

- track the checked checkboxes and typed remarks separately, and
- turning `SelectedType` into a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that merges those values.

In the example below the checked checkboxes are in `selectePayTypeIds` and the typed remarks are in `typedRemarks`.

Notice `SelectedType` is no longer in `data` but now in `computed`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    PaymentType:[
      {Id: 1, Text:"Cash"},
      {Id: 2, Text:"Check"},
      {Id: 3, Text:"Paypal"}
   ],
   selectePayTypeIds: {},
   typedRemarks: {}
  },
  computed: {
    SelectedType: function () {
      var vm = this;
      return Object.keys(vm.selectePayTypeIds).filter(function (selectedPayTypeId) {
            return vm.selectePayTypeIds[selectedPayTypeId];
      }).map(function (selectedPayTypeId) {
            return {PayTypeId: selectedPayTypeId, Remarks: vm.typedRemarks[selectedPayTypeId] || ''}
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
      <p> SelectedType {{ SelectedType }}</p>
      <div v-for="(pay, index) in PaymentType">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectePayTypeIds[pay.Id]" />
          {{pay.Text}}
          <input type="input" v-model="typedRemarks[pay.Id]">
          <!-- What goes here on :value attributes? -->
      </div>
</div>
```

## Making the `SelectedType` computed property editable/assignable again

Since you actually want to also be able to assign values to the `SelectedType` property, we need to define a `set` function in the `SelectedType` computed.

To show an example of value being assigned to the `SelectedType`, have a look at the `created` function below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    PaymentType:[
      {Id: 1, Text:"Cash"},
      {Id: 2, Text:"Check"},
      {Id: 3, Text:"Paypal"}
    ],
    selectePayTypeIds: {},
    typedRemarks: {}
  },
  created: function () {
    this.SelectedType = [{PayTypeId: 2, Remarks: 'remarks about two'}];
  },
  computed: {
    SelectedType: {
      get: function () {
        var vm = this;
        return Object.keys(vm.selectePayTypeIds).filter(function (selectedPayTypeId) {
            return vm.selectePayTypeIds[selectedPayTypeId];
        }).map(function (selectedPayTypeId) {
            return {PayTypeId: selectedPayTypeId, Remarks: vm.typedRemarks[selectedPayTypeId] || ''}
        });
      },
      set: function (newSelectedType) {
        var vm = this;
        newSelectedType.forEach(function(sType) {
          Vue.set(vm.selectePayTypeIds, sType.PayTypeId, true);
          Vue.set(vm.typedRemarks, sType.PayTypeId, sType.Remarks);
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
      <p> SelectedType {{ SelectedType }}</p>
      <div v-for="(pay, index) in PaymentType">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectePayTypeIds[pay.Id]" />
          {{pay.Text}}
          <input type="input" v-model="typedRemarks[pay.Id]">
          <!-- What goes here on :value attributes? -->
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also need `SelectedType` in data because this is the object which i need to submit to API's.

Comment: How are you getting it? Because `this.SelectedType` will still work, doesn't matter if it is at `data` or at `computed`.

Comment: This `SelectedType` is submited to Api's and on Edit request i need to get value from API's and bind those value to the checkbox and inputbox

Comment: I'm sorry, I noticed a mistake and fixed it. If you checked the answer before, please check it again.

Comment: Is there any way to conditionally show the Input? 
`<input type="input" v-model="typedRemarks[pay.Id]">`, Show only when checbox is checked?

Comment: Yes: `<input type="input" v-model="typedRemarks[pay.Id]" :hidden="!selectePayTypeIds[pay.Id]">`

Comment: Yeah answer helped me. I have also upvoted your answer. And i am trying to implement the answer in my own code. I may have some question regarding that.

Comment: Thanks. Did the `:hidden` work? If the issue is more complicated, I suggest posting a new question so others can help you as well.

Comment: I need to use it in v-show. I did :<div v-show ="!selectePayTypeIds[pay.Id]" ...` But it produces a error.

Comment: Where are you adding `v-show`? Adding to the `input` works: `<input type="input" v-model="typedRemarks[pay.Id]" v-show="selectePayTypeIds[pay.Id]">`

Comment: That input should box should be toogle below a table, on checbox click. So i wanted to keep inside a `div`.